# Elastic JSON Search response String mapped to SearchRespone.class

Tags: elasticsearch

GET http://localhost:9200/indexName/type/_search + query.json

Above query to elastic search via HttpClient retruns JSON String

Is there any way to map the json string into SearchResponse.class ? or extracts Hits object from it ?

Comment: SInce you are referring to some Java syntax here, I am assuming you are using the Java API.  Why are you not using the Elastic Client object with your requests?  Using the Client object returns a SearchResponse and you can supply raw JSON to the client.prepareSearch...

Comment: Actually was writing the unit-test cases for it am not using elastic client, Instead using http-client and then to efficiently validate the response, need    to map the jsonString to SearchResponse.class [to get hits and other objects ], Could see some trials on google using ObjectMapper gson, but its not working